# How to use objectmapper for nested json in swift?

Tags: swift, json, objectmapper

I am using object mapper library in swift fro parsing JSON to object and I have a JSON which looks like this:

```
"_links" :     {
    "category.genres":         {
        "href" : "http://dev.abcd.com/api/v1/categories/series/genres"
    }
```

}

I am trying to map href to model but I am not able to find any solution here.
I tried to do

```
genreLink <- (map["_links"]["category.genres",nested: false]["genres"],urlTransform)
```

But it doesn't work, Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think your situation is supported using the nested keys feature of ObjectMapper. This is because of one keys in the nesting already has a period in it. If it didn't the mapping would look like the following:

`genreLink <- (map["_links.category_genre.href"], urlTransform)`

Chaining the mappings as you have done above is not supported. To properly map this, I think you will need to create some model classes (that implement Mappable) for Links and Category.genres or change the API response if possible.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I think I will have to go with the model classes since API response is not in my control.

Comment: @tristan_him, do you mean                                                                                         genreLink <- (map["_links.category_genre.href"], urlTransform)

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

> When you have nested keys which contain ., you can pass the custom nested key delimiter as follows (#629):

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    appName <- map["com.myapp.info->com.myapp.name", delimiter: "->"]
}
```

Reference: [Custom nested key delimiter in mapping](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/pull/629)